# link_to post edit view in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, link-to

Really basic question about link_to that I'm having trouble finding a straight answer to.

So I have an index view that simply lists posts according to user email address.

```
<% @post.each do |post| %>
  <tr>
    <td class="email"><%= link_to post.user.email, post %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

As it stands, this links to the show view for the given post.  How might I make it link to the edit view instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pretty simple:

```
<%= link_to post.user.email, edit_post_path(post) %>
```